# Example of violating the Functor rules in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

I have a data structure for binary tree and a Functor over it

```
data BST a = Empty | Node (BST a) a (BST a)
instance Functor BST  where
  fmap f Empty = Empty
  fmap f (Node l val r) = (Node (fmap f l) (f val  ) (fmap f r))
```

I need to find an example of some BST instance and a function f where the rules of the Functor(Identity,composition)  are **violated**

Can someone point me to the right direction ?

Thanks!

Comment: That implementation looks correct to me, by which I mean, it should respect both the laws.

Comment: Can we find example of f and some BST a where the rules are violated ? Maybe a  BST (BST a) ?

Comment: No. Are you sure you copied the exercise correctly from wherever you got it?

Comment: Is it your exercise to define a new Functor instance?

Comment: Another possibility, though I think it unlikely: although this implementation is a functor on Hask, the name "BST" suggests that you are dealing with binary search trees, where there are data type invariants. This implementation does not necessarily preserve those invariants, and perhaps this can be expressed by pointing out that it is not a functor on the subcategory of `Ord`ered types and monotonic functions. But it's a pretty serious stretch -- you would need to be reading quite an advanced piece of writing for that to be a sensible way to talk about this.

Comment: I asked :"Is it OK to provide an example of specific parameter values ( function and a BST )  that if provided to fmap will cause a violation of the factor laws ?" The response : "Yes, please! I had exactly that in mind. Please also briefly (1-2 sentences) explain what's going wrong."

Comment: I needed to define  a Functor over the BST  and then find example where it breaks the rules.

Comment: @GilShafriri If you also control the `Functor` instance, then write a different, buggier instance.

Comment: There are some terminological issues here: you don't define a functor *over* `BST`; `BST` *is* a functor if there is a definition of `fmap` (as shown) that obeys the functor laws. Your instructor may have in mind something like "If you map `\x -> -x` over a value of type `BST Int`, the result is no longer a binary search tree", but that doesn't involve a violation of the functor laws. The type `BST a` doesn't itself enforce the search-tree invariants (e.g. that all values on the left are less than the root).

Comment: Yes that possible but he still mentioned a violation of the Functor rules which ,as all of you are saying, looks impossible with my implementation.

Comment: @chepner terminologically speaking... I disagree. In maths, a functor _is_ something you define “over” a type constructor. `BST` is just the mapping _object→object_, but only by adding also a _morphism→morphism_ one (i.e., `fmap`), you make it a functor. Just because that's _possible_, doesn't strictly speaking mean `BST` _is_ a functor. Maybe what you mean is that a **Hask** functor instance is always uniquely determined by the type constructor, i.e. that _any_ implementation different from the OP's will violate the functor laws.

Answer (score 0):

You wont find any example because your definition holds the laws of functor. You can proof it by induction on the depth of the tree. The base case is the 0-depth tree (i.e. `Empty`), then proof for the `Node` case. The proof is long but straightforward.

## Edit:

re-reading your question, maybe you are looking for a definition of `fmap` that type check's but doesn't hold the funtor laws. Just use

```
data BST a = Empty | Node (BST a) a (BST a)
instance Functor BST  where
  fmap f Empty = Empty
  fmap f (Node l val r) = (Node (fmap f r) (f val  ) (fmap f l))
--                                      |- notice            |- notice
```

Why it doesn't hold the laws? That's on you. below is the proof that your definition does hold. Try to built your own proof on why my definition doesn't

## First law

```
fmap id == id
```

#### Base Case

```
fmap id Empty = Empty    -- by definition of fmap
              = id Empty -- by definition of id
=> fmap id = id          -- by eta-reducing both sides of the equation
```

#### Recursive case

Supose that the hypotesis is true for all trees of a given depth `D` (or less). Proof for the the tree one depth `(D + 1)`

```
fmap id (Node l val r) = Node (fmap id l) (id val) (fmap id r) -- by definition of fmap
                       = Node (fmap id l) val      (fmap id r) -- by applying id to val
                       = Node l val r                          -- by induction hyp. fmap id l == l
                       = id (Node l val r)                     -- by definition of id
=> fmap id             = id                                    -- by eta-reducing both sides of the equation
```

## Second law

```
 fmap g . fmap f == fmap (g . f)
```

#### Base Case

```
-- Eq 1
(fmap g . fmap f) Empty = fmap g (fmap f Empty)  -- by definition of .
                        = fmap g Empty           -- by definition of fmap
                        = Empty                  -- by definition of fmap
-- Eq 2
fmap (g . f) Empty      = Empty                  -- by definition of fmap

-- Therefore
(fmap g . fmap f) Empty = fmap (g . f) Empty     -- By transition of equality on Eq1 and Eq2
fmap g . fmap f         = fmap (g . f)           -- by eta-reducing both sides of the equation
```

#### Recursive case

Supose that the hypotesis is true for all trees of a given depth `D` (or less). Proof for the the tree one depth `(D + 1)`

```
-- Eq 1
fmap (g . f) (Node l val r) = Node (fmap (g . f) l) 
                                   ((g . f) val) 
                                   (fmap (g . f) r) -- by definition of fmap

                            = Node ((fmap g . fmap f) l) 
                                   ((g . f) val) 
                                   ((fmap g . fmap f) r) -- by induction hyp.

-- Eq 2
(fmap g . fmap f) (Node l val r) = fmap g (fmap f (Node l val r)) -- dy definition of .
                                 = fmap g $ Node (fmap f l) 
                                                 (f val) 
                                                 (fmap f r)       -- by definition of fmap
                                 = Node (fmap g (fmap f l))
                                        (g (f val))
                                        (fmap g (fmap f r))       -- by definition of fmap
                                 = Node ((fmap g . fmap f) l) 
                                        ((g . f) val) 
                                        ((fmap g . fmap f) r)     -- by induction hyp.

fmap (g . f) (Node l val r) = (fmap g . fmap f) (Node l val r)    -- By transition of equality on Eq1 and Eq2
fmap (g . f)                = (fmap g . fmap f)                   -- by eta-reducing both sides of the equation
```

Comment: Finally I got a confirmation that the functor is not suppose to be violating any functor law but he claim the implementation is "buggy". Why ? because a BST can become a non BST after providing some function f ( for example (\x -> (-x) ) to the functor. I have problem accepting this "buggy" terminology because any violation of some invariant in a functor can be considered "buggy".

Comment: If you refer to @danielWagner comment. He claims that you _can_ implement a functor instance so it becomes buggy, not that _this_implementation is buggy. An example of a buggy instance would be the one in the edit of my answer

Comment: What does it mean become "buggy" - Functor can change some some invariant of the data it is  operates on. I feel that "buggy" is not the right term for this reality.

Comment: Of course I can write a Functor that violates the laws but I don't think this is very interesting. The professor makse the claim that every Functor over BST is "buggy". And I have a problem to agree with that.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting lost. Your question is "can I find an example where functor laws are violated for this particular type and instance". The answer is no, you can't. What all this "buggy"-issue has to do with your question?

Comment: The original ask was to write a Functor instance  for BST and then show it is "buggy". That all. From this statement I'm trying to figure out what is needed

Comment: The definition of buggy is ambiguous in this case. If your professor said "all functor instances are buggy", then @danielWagner's comment makes sense. A functor instance would imply that your `BST` can hold any type `a`. Including types that aren't comparable, making you binary search tree useless for such types.

Comment: I agree this is ambiguous  definition. I have hard time to accept that changing some invariant of the data structure  in a Functor, by applying a function provided to it ,is "buggy".